# GCC4.3.3: variable used in a macro marked as unused

Tags: c++, gcc, macros, warnings

I'm compiling legacy code with 4.3.3 and am using `-Werror` at the moment. For some reason, even though a variable is read in a macro, `gcc` thinks it is unused - I don't understand why.

Here are the snippets:

```
void MyClass::processEvent ()
{
   i32 event = getEvent();
   i32 handle = getHandle();

   DEBUG_ENTRY( __OBSV_KEY__, __LINE__,  
                "MyClass::processEvent() event=%d", event,
                " (handle=%d)", handle);
}
```

The debug entry macro (only ENTRY2 is used in current code, ENTRY is legacy):

```
#define DEBUG_ENTRY( MOD, NR, STR1, DAT1, STR2, DAT2 ) \
           ENTRY(MOD,NR,DAT1,DAT2)                     \
           ENTRY2(MOD, NR, STR1, DAT1, STR2, DAT2 )
```

Entry macro code (stripped to relevant function call only):

```
#define ENTRY2(MOD, NR, STR1, DAT1, STR2, DAT2 )         \
        {                                                \
           Observer::setEntry( (int) DAT1, (int) DAT2 ); \
        }
```

And finally the function itself:

```
int Observer::setEntry (int  a_nInt1, int  a_nInt2)
{
   // relevant part only: member variables set to a_nInt1 and a_nInt2
   p_NewEntry->m_nInt1 = a_nInt1;
   p_NewEntry->m_nInt2 = a_nInt2; 

   return ERR_NONE;
}
```

So to sum up, both `event` and `handle` are passed down the macro chain to the actual function, where their value **is** read by saving the values to that object's member variables.

Why does GCC think that `event` and `handle` are unused when using the macro? If I avoid the macro and paste the same code instead, the warning is not emitted. Can I somehow make it see the light without having to resort to using the `UNUSED` macro to silence the warning?

Comment: Can you provide a [MCVE] that reproduces the warning please.

Comment: You wouldn't happen to have two alternative definitions of one or more of those macros, and one of them expands to nothing?

Comment: @molbdnilo - if he is using `-Werror` I think he should get an error for redefined macro first (or otherwise just a warning)...  without the full example we are just guessing : (

Comment: Other then @πάνταῥεῖ's point (which is necessary), are you saying that this works ok with newer compilers? - in my compiler > version 5, I see no error like this so maybe its a bug in the older version. If you just want to compile this thing (and get around that issue for now) you can void-cast the "unused" variables `(void) event;` - and then check if the code works as expected etc....

Comment: Interesting. Compiling a minimal example does not seem to trigger the warning. I wonder why - it's probably impossible for anyone to tell without having the code, though, eh? I'll try to expand the example to try and trigger it.

Comment: @Soukyuu maybe in your larger example it really is not used (somehow the include path is missing or something)... have you to tried to compile it without `-Werror` to see if `setEntry()` is called (and add some printf in there)?

Comment: @code_fodder There won't be a redefinition error if they're in different translation units or if one is, say, `#if _DEBUG` and the other one isn't.

Answer (score 0):

I dug deeper and it seems I got confused by visual studio reporting an `NDEBUG` define as unset when it was indeed set - there are several modules and the `NDEBUG` define can be set per module. So it's as @molbdnilo guessed: the macro resolved to nothing for that specific module, resulting in an unset variable warning - thanks for the hint.

```
#ifndef NDEBUG // this was set for the affected module, but appeared unset in visual studio
   // en/disable old observer
   //#define OBSERVER_1_ON

   // en/disable new observer
   #define OBSERVER_2_ON
#endif  
#include obsv2Func.h // this is where the ENTRY2 macro is defined

// class functions here

void MyClass::processEvent ()
{
   i32 event = getEvent();
   i32 handle = getHandle();

   // expands to nothing, because ENTRY2 is not defined
   DEBUG_ENTRY( __OBSV_KEY__, __LINE__,  
                "MyClass::processEvent() event=%d", event,
                " (handle=%d)", handle);
}
```

obsv2Func.h

```
#ifdef OBSERVER_2_ON
   #define ENTRY2(MOD, NR, STR1, DAT1, STR2, DAT2 )         \
           {                                                \
              Observer::setEntry( (int) DAT1, (int) DAT2 ); \
           }
#else
   #define ENTRY2(MOD, NR, STR1, DAT1, STR2, DAT2 )
#endif
```

So there is no bug in my version of GCC (which I am forced to use), just unclean code on my end. It also explains why replacing the macro with the actual code behind it hides the warning - that made the code unaffected by `#ifdef NDEBUG`, so the variable was read.

My solution is either to put the unused variable in the `MyClass::processEvent()` function into an `#ifndef NDEBUG` block as well if there are many calls to the `DEBUG_ENTRY` macro in that module

```
void MyClass::processEvent ()
{
   i32 event = getEvent();
   #ifndef NDEBUG
   i32 handle = getHandle();
   #endif

   switch (event)
   {
      case 0:
         DEBUG_ENTRY( __OBSV_KEY__, __LINE__,  
                      "MyClass::processEvent() event=%d", event,
                      " (handle=%d)", handle);
         // some other code not affected by NDEBUG here
         break;
      //some more cases
      default:
         DEBUG_ENTRY( __OBSV_KEY__, __LINE__,  
                      "MyClass::processEvent() event=%d", event,
                      " (handle=%d)", handle);
         // some other code not affected by NDEBUG here
         break;
   }
}
```

or just use `getEvent()` and `getHandle` directly in the macro calls if there is only one call to the `DEBUG_ENTRY` macro in the function.

```
         DEBUG_ENTRY( __OBSV_KEY__, __LINE__,  
                      "MyClass::processEvent() event=%d", getEvent(),
                      " (handle=%d)", getHandle());
```

Sorry for not providing a complete example in the question, I'll make sure to do so next time.